# Removing extra output from "su - <username> sh -c '<command>'" in a shell script

Tags: python, bash, sh, python-2.x, su

In my python script, I'm trying to get the output of a command that needs to be run as a different user. So I have this code:

```
username = "<username>"
cmdToRun = "<command>"
fullCmd = 'sudo su - %s sh -c "%s"' % (username, cmdToRun)

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(fullCmd.encode("ascii")), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
response = proc.communicate()
output = response[0]
```

Problem is, I'm picking up some extra output from "su - %s sh -c ...". So I get something like this:

```
> print output
Logging in as <username>...
<Actual output of the command>
```

How can I get rid of the extra output, **not** knowing what it may be, but keep the output of the command I'm trying to run.

Comment: Don't build a string just to parse it with `shlex`; just define a list in the first place. `full_cmd = ['sudo', 'su', '-', username, 'sh', '-c', cmdToRun]`.

Comment: Use `sudo -u user` instead of going through `su`